# cron: как из него выполнить скрипт?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

Не могу понять, почему не работают задания в cron'е

Вопрос довольно традиционный, я уже набил с кроном кучу шишек, но воз и ныне там.

У меня - свежая убунта 22 LTS.

мне надо раз в день запускать некоторое задание (docker start <имя контейнера>)

я ищу какой то - *самый простой* - способ это сделать.

Ищу уже два дня, склояюсь к тому, что проще написать самому... но пока надеюсь, что не придётся заниматься глуповатой работой (*ну, еще одного шедулера только не хватало*)

Что у меня не получается:

в диреткории /etc/cron.d

я пробую создавать задания.

Уже наученный горьким опытом, я составляю имена заданий только из букв, цифр и минусов (без точек и подчеркиваний)

Внутри такого задания с именем `robotdocsstatus` написано

```
    * * * * * konst date >> /tmp/date-from-cron.txt
```

и это задание действительно выполняется раз в минуту. В файл /tmp/date-from-cron.txt раз в минуту дописывается строчка с датой.

Потом я осмелел и написал в `/etc/cron.d` второй файл с именем `robotdocsstatus-02-00` и содержимым

```
    0 2 * * * konst date >> /tmp/date-from-cron-02-00.txt
```

И это тоже сработало!

Но.. на этом всё. Любые попытки выполнить что нибудь, отлчное от записи времени в файл в диретокрии /tmp - не работает, причем молча.

То есть, команда

```
    sudo systemctl status cron
```

выводит информацию вида

```
    Mar 28 09:49:01 robotics cron[10233]: (*system*robotdocsstatus-02-00) RELOAD (/etc/cron.d/robotdocsstatus-02-00)
```

и - молчок. Время выполнения скрипта (10:00) наступает, в скрипте написано буквально

```
    00 10 * * * konst docker start run_robotdocsstatus-cont
```

Команда `sudo systemctl status cron` не показывает в 10:00 каких либо действий. То есть, как она написала что RELOAD - потом ничего не изменилось...

Кроме того, если бы команда `docker start run_robotdocsstatus-cont` выполнилась - то создался бы лог файл самого докера. Но он не создаётся.

у меня уже нет идей, что еще проверить.

Пните меня, пожалуйста, в нужную сторону?

Если Вы посоветуете мне что нить попроще и подружелюбнее, чем крон (pm2? только как его на эту убунту водрзить? ncron от Умпутуна? но вопрос вс тот же -как устанавливать) - тоже буду рад.

Спасибо

Comment: Сделать systemd-таймер и перестать страдать с кроном?

Comment: указывайте полный путь к команде  * * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/domain.com/backup.php > /dev/null 2>&1     # https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-ubuntu-1804

Comment: Спасибо, оба совета - очень крутые! Всё время забываю, что у крона переменных окружения  - кот наплакал...  А как надо узнавать полный путь - командой where?

Comment: @nexoma если команда `date` работает, значит и команды `docker` и `php` тоже должны работать без полного пути, потому что они все лежат в одном и том же `/usr/bin`

Comment: which программа # вот так

Comment: андрей, тут нюанс есть,  date и подобное есть внутренние команды bash, потому и работают

Comment: прекрасно!       * * * * * .   ~/.profile; your cmd

Comment: @nexoma `date` это **не** внутренняя команда bash, поэтому такого нюанса здесь нет

Comment: Я в крон записываю не комманды, а скрипт, в котором содержится всё необходимое. Его и модифицировать легче и всякие там переменные добавлять и вот это вот всё. Т.е. `* * * /data/sh/script-4-cron.sh`