# cron: почему он работает по UTC? и как его от этого отучить?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

Уважаемые господа,

я [задавал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1508806/) вопрос о своих мучениях с Кроном.

И история получила неожиданное продолжение.

загляну на утро в свои логи, я обнаружил, что моё **тестовое** задание выполнилось... барабанная дробь... на три часа позже!

То есть, по UTC, а не по московскому времени!

я пишу этот вопрос, уже пережИв большую часть эмоций, но даже сейчас  меня почти нет приличных слов. Казалось бы, на заботливо разложенных создателями системы граблях мы уже почти научились нанцевать, но год от года они дарят нам всё новые сюрпризы...

почему, черт побери, выполнить `sudo rm * -rf` в корневом разделе убунты можно только после длительной борьбы, предупреждений и отказа от ответственности, а скрипт можно МОЛЧА поставить не на то время, на которое ты хочешь, и система даже не заикнётся об этом?

в общем, вопрос простой: как этому крону сказать, чтобы работал в той же таймзоне, что и я?

Спасибо!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/54364 ?

Comment: Ну собственно логичный вопрос — какая таймзона на сервере вообще?

Comment: Какое время в биосе? Какая таймзона в биосе? (добавьте вывод команды `sudo hwclock --debug`). Какое время в ядре? Добавьте вывод команды `timedatectl`. Что у вас написано в `/etc/timezone`?